# php is finish loaded then only start load javascript. Is it true?

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to ask javascript wait for mysql assign value to php variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322161/how-to-ask-javascript-wait-for-mysql-assign-value-to-php-variable)

I heard people said php codes will be finished loaded then only will start loading javascript. Info at [How to ask javascript wait for mysql assign value to php variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322161/how-to-ask-javascript-wait-for-mysql-assign-value-to-php-variable)

But When I wrote :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("<?php echo $username; ?>");
</script>
<?php $username = "abc"; ?>
```

It fail to alert the value of php variable. It is because javascript is loaded at first, then only start loading php. So the fact of server-site script is finish loaded then only start load client-site script is wrong?

If javascript can be executed before php, then I have problem to ask javascript wait for mysql assign value to php variable. Please help me to solve this problem at [How to ask javascript wait for mysql assign value to php variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322161/how-to-ask-javascript-wait-for-mysql-assign-value-to-php-variable)

Comment: I see some answers that say PHP will *finish* before the JS execution *starts*, however, while this is true in the general case, this is not absolutely true -- imagine that the HTML is *streamed* back to the client (say it's a 10MB request) and the client *begins* the HTML processing before the PHP completes the (entire 10MB) HTML generation. That is, the JavaScript and PHP *can*, in certain scenarios, be running "at the same time", but will *still not be able to interact*: it is only the *result* of the PHP code which is transmitted to the client.

Comment: @pst, ya, this is what I worry about. If database table has too many data to search/retrieve, php will be slower than javascript. So javascript can't display the output properly. Example codes at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322161/how-to-ask-javascript-wait-for-mysql-assign-value-to-php-variable

Answer (score 9):

PHP is executed on the web-server, generating an html (or whatever) page to be displayed by the browser. JavaScript is executed on the client-side, in the user's browser, therefore php has, by definition, finished executing before JavaScript executes.

You seem to be assuming that php runs, then JavaScript is run, in the *same place*. Which is a fallacy; the problem you're having is that you assign the JavaScript variable to the value of the `$username` variable *before* the php script has assigned/evaluated the variable; which should transform, on the server, from:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("<?php echo $username; ?>");
</script>
<?php $username = "abc"; ?>
```

To, on the client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("");
</script>
```

Therefore, while your script appears to do nothing, or do the wrong thing, it's doing exactly what you told it to do. You should try and rearrange your code a little to:

```
<?php $username = "abc"; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("<?php echo $username; ?>");
</script>
```

Which allows php to evaluate/assign the variable, and then have the variable set/available in the `alert()` statement.

Comment: Pedantically, there is no requirement that PHP has *finished* executing before (any) JavaScript is run -- it is a more fundamental idea than that, which was explained: only the *result* of the PHP execution is transmitted to the client. Otherwise, nice answer +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

PHP is run on the server BEFORE any of the javascript is parsed. You need to assign your variable before it used. That's the problem above.

Comment: So that mean javascript can be executed before mysql right? How to ask javascript wait for mysql assign value to php variable?

Comment: @zac: php/mysql is run on the server, long before any JavaScript is executed. JavaScript doesn't *have* to wait for mysql/php to run, it happens that way automatically (outside of AJAX anyway, which is a separate question entirely).

Comment: wat if the database has too many data to search or fetch, so javascript will be executed before mysql finish fetch the data from database to php array?

Answer (score 3):

PHP does not load or execute Javascript. Here is an order of execution:

1. The user requests data from your web server.
2. Your web server executes your PHP script, which outputs some HTML/Javascript.
3. The web server sends the HTML/Javascript to the user's browser.
4. The user's browser renders the HTML and executes the Javascript.

So yes, the PHP will finish executing before the Javascript is executed.

Comment: but for my example codes on my question, js will finish executing before php.

Comment: No, it won't. The webserver will locate all of the PHP code (encapsulated in `<?php ?>` blocks) and execute it before the output (HTML and Javascript) is ever sent to the user's browser. The data the browser receives will contain no PHP code at all.

Answer (score 0):

> I heard people said php codes will be
>   finished loaded then only will start
>   loading javascript.

This is absolutely true, your server scripts will be run first.

The reason it doesn't `alert()` anything is because `$username` does not even exist yet...

Once the PHP script runs it is done, unless you call more from AJAX.

Comment: $username is php, so it should be finish executed before js. So why i alert() nothing?

Comment: Because your server goes through line by line returning and echoing out what the client will see on the frontend. When it got to $username, the PHP echoed it out as an empty string since you had not defined it yet. Your browser just sees alert("");

Comment: @zac1987:Because you are not outputting the result of the PHP statement `$username = "abc";` in any way that your Javascript code can use. Try `<script type="text/javascript">alert("<?php $username = "abc"; echo $username; ?>")</script>`

Answer (score 0):

PHP is run at the web server. It parses the file and returns HTML like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("");
</script>
```

When it has arrived at the client side, no variables are being set anymore as you can see.