# Clearing notification onclick/toggle()

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, notifications

So I have a notifications system set up and it all works perfect except when I come to clearing the notification. Its clears ok when the div opens but it also clears if I refresh the page without the div been opened at all, I'm not wanting the notification to clear until the user has opened the notifications div. How would I go about doing this?

Any help or someone that could point me in the right direction will be greatly appreciated

Thank you

I have been using this line of code to clear the notification

```
<?php user_core::clear_notifications($user1_id); ?>
```

And this code  is the `OnClick toggle()`

```
<div class="alert_header_item_container">
    <a onclick="toggle('alert_dropdown');">
        <div class="alert_header_item" id="alerts"></div>
        <?
        $sql  = "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE notification_targetuser=".$user1_id." AND notification_status = '1'" ;
        $chant= mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
        $num = mysqli_num_rows($chant);
        if($num==1) {
            echo '<div class="alert_header_item_new" id="alerts"></div>';
        } else {
            echo "";
        }
        ?>
    </a>
```

Comment: PHP is server side and runs before javascript (which is client side). They aren't love partners. What you'll want is to send an ajax request to say `"Hey I've read this notification/clicked this div so don't show them anymore."` Cause right now your PHP is loading and saying `yeah, you've read it, because I ran before your onclick event was ever triggered javascript mwuahah`. (*excuse the sad humor, not enough coffee yet.*)

Comment: That makes complete sense. I'll give it a blast and see the result. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it did! Let me know if you need more help!

Comment: I don't have a clue how I'd do the ajax

Comment: hang tight, I'll throw up some pseudo code for you now.

Comment: You are a diamond Darren. I am in the know of Ajax, just never done anything where it includes Onclick function before. But once you have mocked something up I will look over it and read into all you've done for a better understanding for future references.

Comment: There you go mate, any questions just ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is [**`this`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6391609/2518525):

> PHP does not load or execute Javascript. Here is an order of
>   execution:
>
> 1. The user requests data from your web server.
> 2. Your web server executes your PHP script, which outputs some HTML/Javascript.
> 3. The web server sends the HTML/Javascript to the user's browser.
> 4. The user's browser renders the HTML and executes the Javascript. So yes, the PHP will
>      finish executing before the Javascript is executed.

Basically your `PHP` is completed before you even toggle the `onclick` event.

---

What you really want to be doing is something like this:

Structure your `HTML` something like this.

```
<div class="alert_header_item_container">
    <a id="read-notifications">
        <div class="alert_header_item" id="alerts"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Now we'd run an ajax request (*when the document loads*) to fetch the notifications

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'notifications.php',
        data: {id: user_id},
    }).success(function(data){
        $('alerts').html(data);
    });
});
```

Which would call `notifications.php` where you'd run your `php/sql` to fetch the notifications:

```
<?php
$user1_id = $_POST['id']; // then sanitize as needed
$sql = "SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE notification_targetuser=" . $user1_id . " AND notification_status = '1'";
$chant = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($chant);
if ($num == 1) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc()){
        // make notifications markup
    }
   echo MARKUP_FROM_ABOVE
}
?>
```

As for the `onclick` event, you'd do something like this (to a seperate php file that will update the notifications to set them to **read** (which is probably **`0`** ?)):

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#read-notifications', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'readnotifications.php',
        data: {id: user_id},
    }).success(function(data) {
        // do what you need to do as notifications were read.
    });
});
```

And on `readnotifications.php` you'd run an `sql query` that would update the notifications for `$_POST['id']` (*The user id*) to **`0`** (read).

Comment: @Dave Perfectly alright. I'm glad it was what you were after! We all have to start somewhere :-)