# load JS function before PHP validation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to (echo) call a javascript function from PHP when the form is submitted. I have an error that `function is not defined`. I do understand that PHP is loaded before Javascript, therefore, the function is not defined in PHP call.

I could create `onclick` even in the HTML section but the example below is part of a bigger program and PHP script is in a separate file which is included at the top of the HTML page, the function will also receive different parameters and perform different operations when called and it will be an AJAX function. Also, I have some variables loaded as page renders and I only want to call the JS function at a certain point in the program. Moving PHP to the bottom is not elegant as I would have to add some PHP at the top some at the bottom to have all variables included.

Is there a way to include the PHP part at the top and still call an AJAX function whenever required with a range of parameters? Or even better what is the best way of doing this sort of thing? I believe echo'ing javascript through PHP is not the best practice.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['a'])) {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>example('hello');</script>";
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>printSome(0,0);</script>";
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>                             
<html>
<body>

<form method="post">
  <input type="text"> 
  <input type="submit" name="a">
</form>

</body>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  function example(variable)
  {
    window.alert(variable);
  }

  function printSome(type, quantity)
  {
   return $.ajax({
   url                   : 'http://localhost/printDoc.php',
   type                  : 'POST',
   dataType              : 'json',
   data                  : {
                              DTStype      : type,
                              DTSquantity  : quantity
                           },
   cache                 : false
});
}

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you can research "window.onload" function...

Comment: You can only do this by ajax, otherwise PHP always comes before JavaScript

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL I agree but the method will then be loaded when page loads and I just want to load when required by PHP, not at any other point.

Comment: You are executing the function before it is declared, what do you expect?

Comment: @user2486 could you show me an ajax example which will work?

Comment: To solve the problems of a bad design, you should fix the design, otherwise you would be adding potential errors to those that already exist.

Comment: @JorgeSB the design I follow is PHP, HTML + CSS and Javascript. I agree that design might not be perfect but I just add bits to a large program which I have not build myself, this is a principle and I do not want to change it too much. I want to learn the best practice of coding and this question is to help me achieve that. Do you know how to create right AJAX call to make this example work with including PHP script at the top?

Comment: Putting a good solution on the wrong functionality won't guarantee you better results.

Comment: @JorgeSB a good answer will point both things a solution and a path to do it better. It would be a valuable information if there is a way of designing the code in a better way, I'm a junior developer so I still have a lot to learn and get better habits with more experience. Therefore purposely I asked if there is any better way of doing this thing in general.

Comment: UZIERSKI Start by tracking the full functionality. It then separates the code into PHP files for operations that are performed strictly on the server and JS files for the client. Having a file with only JS code, helps you to make a debug more tidy and easy to understand.

Comment: @JorgeSB that's how it works in the general code but I simplified it putting it all together for this example only. Usually, however, javascript is on the bottom of the HTML code as it is easier to send parameters and keep the client/server distinguished.

Comment: UZIERSKI, What you must do is attach the events to the HTML elements. That's a good practice that is used in frameworks like Angular.
That way the HTML is only tags and serves only as a view and the JS will have controller code.

Comment: @JorgeSB I can't agree more with you I believe the best practice is to use HTML as a link between PHP and Javascript operations. The thing is I'm not good with the events and that where I occasionally need help. It would be good to see how it can work in this situation with AJAX. Do you know how I can do it as I do not want to make a discussion too long here? The answers I received I already know about them, I'm looking for something more elegant. I have some variables loaded as page renders and some functions which need to execute at certain points, therefore, solutions given are not good

Comment: UZIERSKI, So what would you say to someone who needs to handle events? . That's to do on my part.
Stackoverflow is not a coding service.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" name="a">
</form>

</body>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  function example(variable)
  {
    window.alert(variable);
  }

</script>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['a'])) {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>example('hello');</script>";
}

?>
</html>
```

Comment: regarding execution check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391556/php-is-finish-loaded-then-only-start-load-javascript-is-it-true

Comment: thank you for this answer but is there a way to include PHP part on top of the HTML to make this work? Would AJAX call work?

Comment: this is not an ideal solution for me as I have some variables loaded as page loads therefore I will have to include PHP script at the bottom and at the top

Comment: Instead of "echo ..." you can save the snippet in a variable and use echo later. So you can include the php on top of the page but print the stuff later.

Comment: @DanFromGermany hmm that is not a bad idea if I assign that variable empty and then when times comes it will initialise that function as the page renders. I like this idea but do you think an ajax call would work better?

Answer (score 1):

This happens just because when it tries to execute the example function, it was not yet defined.
You can overcome this by using an event listener:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  example('hello');
});
```

More than that, having script tags outside body is not valid, although probably most browser would still run it. Therefore, I suggest you to move the entire php section of the page somewhere inside the body../body tag.

Comment: thank you for this answer, is there a way to include the PHP script at the top of the document and make this work? Possibly with ajax call or something?

Comment: I have some variables loaded from PHP as the page renders, therefore, I would have to include two different PHP scripts one at the top and one at the bottom. I sure there must be more elegant solution