# Body onload script is executed before PHP the PHP script

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to do some things with PHP and then the window should be closed.

This is the code:

```
<?php
do_this_in_server();
do_that();
?>

<html>
    <head>
    <script>
   function realClose()
    {
      var win=window.open("","_top","","true");
      win.opener=true;
      win.close();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
<body onload="realClose()">
</body>
```

The javascript and therefore closure of the window is executed before the PHP functions have finished. Any ideas?

Comment: What do the functions do? How do you know that they didn't finish?

Comment: Better use ajax and get json response then call realClose function

Comment: It is not possible that the JS is executed before the PHP scripts have finished. The complete HTML is only sent to the browser after the PHP is finished.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider is right. Impossible to happen that. Absolutely impossible

Comment: _The javascript and therefore closure of the window is executed before the PHP functions have finished._ really Strange!!! Where are you testing your application in filesystem or in a webserver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **impossible** for a javascript to execute sooner than the PHP in the same file. 
I suggest you double check whether the PHP really is not executed. (it either doesn't work at all, or executes before the javascript as it should). If you are checking by some other php script, keep in mind that it can have a delay on its own.

Since your code doesn't give us a clue what it should actually do, it's impossible to give you a more specific answer.

A little research would tell you that if you tried, for example check the answers on [How to ask javascript wait for mysql assign value to php variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322161/how-to-ask-javascript-wait-for-mysql-assign-value-to-php-variable)

Comment: The PHP was faulty

Answer (score 1):

```
"Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it."
```

You can not close a window open by script itself.
   yet i would like to give you few suggestion.

- To use ajax call for do_that() function.

Comment: it works in internet explorer and chrome. Not on Mozilla tho.

Comment: yes You are right. Although i don't think its a good idea to close a window on which end use is working eventually :P